# Else statement's code is also printing even though if statement is true

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

This is the code:

```
<%
  try 
        {
            String enteredOtp = request.getParameter("otps");           
            String actualOtp = (String) session.getAttribute("OTP");
            
            if (enteredOtp.equals(actualOtp)) 
            {
                String eemail = (String)session.getAttribute("eemail"); 
                Connection con;                      
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","12345");                               
                             
                Statement stm = con.createStatement();
                String m = "select * from empinfo where EEMailID='"+eemail+"'";
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(m);
                while(rs.next()){
                if(eemail.equals(rs.getString("EEMailID"))){
                String uid = rs.getString("EUsername"); %>               
                <a href="ChangePassword.jsp?uid=<%=uid%>">Change Password</a> 
<%              
                 }
                 
                 else{ 
                        out.println("Enter Registered Email Id only");
                     }
            } 
}           
            else {
               out.println("WRONG OTP ENTERED");
            }
}       
  catch(Exception e){
     out.println(e);
  }

        %>
```

I don't know why the else statement's code(

```
else{ 
           out.println("Enter Registered Email Id only");
    }
```

) is now not at all printing, even though the 'IF statement' is false.
What changes can do in the code to solve this error?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: please fix the code formatting (needs proper indentation) to make it easily readable

Comment: @Unmitigated I wan to check if the email is registered in empinfo or not if not then it will display the else part and if "if condition is true it will show the link to change the password of that particular username.

Comment: @kleopatra I did some changes in the code will you please now review it?

Answer (score 2):

The `else` is entered for every non-matching row. If you want the print statement to be triggered only if there are no matches, you would need to move it outside the loop and introduce some variable to track whether any have been matched. But it doesn't look like you need a loop at all. Why iterate the entire table just to query it again with the ID you already have? You can simplify the flow to a single query and no loops:

```
Statement stm = con.createStatement();
String m = "select * from empinfo where EEMailID='"+eemail+"'";
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(m);
if (rs.next()) {
    // print
} else {
    out.println("Enter Registered Email Id only");
}
```

P.S. Watch out for [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: I did as you suggested but now it is not at all printing else when if statement's condition is false @shmosel

Comment: I edited the code in question where I did changes as you suggested. Still having error as written in the above comment.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. You don't need a `while` loop.

Comment: ok, I just changed while loop to if loop and it worked. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

you could just add a break statement inside the if statement and that should help with performance optimization too. to do this, just add a break at the end of your while(rs1.next()) and add an if statement that checks for the end of the list so it knows when it can determine whether the email can be found

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).